# Set-DnsServerCache: Failed to connect to DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell, ttl, remoting

I am trying to change my computer's DNS cache max time to live.

It is not in any domain, I am the full administrator on the computer - built-in administrator account + disabled group policy "Run all admins in admin approval mode".

I have RSAT DNS tools installed:

['Get-WindowsCapability -Name RSAT.dns* -online' result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UbwW.png)

When trying `Set-DnsServerCache -MaxTtl 2.00:00:00` I get the following error:

`Set-DnsServerCache: Failed to connect to DNS server <computer name>. Please check if the server name is valid and is reachable.`

I thought it might be some sort of remoting issue, so I also did:

```
$s = New-PSSession
Invoke-Command -command {Import-Module dnsserver} -Session $s
Import-PSSession -Session $s -Module dnsserver -Prefix RemoteDNS
Set-RemoteDNSDnsServerCache -MaxTtl 2.00:00:00
```

Same error.

I got 0 results on the net for the error.

Comment: Is your computer a DNS server? If not, then that's the problem. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/set-dnsservercache?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: @joeqwerty, oh... yeah now setting the ttl makes much more sense. That's the problem, it is NOT a DNS server. But, then, how do I change the default ttl of the DNS cache?

Comment: For max (not default) see https://serverfault.com/questions/452524/reduce-windows-dns-service-caching-on-window

Comment: The registry fix from @dave_thompson_085 is likely your best/only option without your own DNS server. Note as explained in that link, you can only REDUCE the configured TTL, not increase it as I suspect you're trying to do by setting a 2 day TTL. If the domain owner has set a 1 hour TTL and you set it to 2 days, then the effective TTL will be 1 hour. But you can set it shorter to get your cache to refresh sooner.

Comment: @KeithLangmead, I'm trying to increase it and there is no domain. My router is the DNS server and it has a TTL of 2 days but my Windows 10 computer only keeps a 1 day TTL cache and I want to change that.